# How to achieve flat shading with light calculated at centroids?

Tags: opengl, 3d, glsl, shader

I'd like to write a GLSL shader program for a per-face shading. My first attempt uses the `flat` interpolation qualifier with *provoking vertices*. I use the flat interpolation for both normal and position vertex attributes which gives me the desired old-school effect of solid-painted surfaces.

Although the rendering looks correct, the shader program doesn't actually do the right job:

1. The light calculation is still performed on a per-fragment basis (in the fragment shader),
2. The position vector is taken from the provoking vertex, not the triangle's centroid (right?).

Is it possible to apply the illumination equation **once**, to the **triangle's centroid**, and then use the calculated color value for the whole primitive? How to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a geometry shader whose input is a triangle and whose output is a triangle. Pass normals and positions to it from the vertex shader, calculate the centroid yourself (by averaging the positions), and do the lighting, passing the output color as an output variable to the fragment shader, which just reads it in and writes it out.

Comment: That's a good idea! But what is the performance impact of introducing the additional shading stage? Theoretically, your approach should be _much_ faster, as it calculates the illumination equation once per primitive. On the other hand, while skimming through related questions and answers, I found that people perceive geometry shading as a very slow technique. Maybe these are just prejudices, but it's always worth to ask.

Comment: Expanding geometry shaders (i.e. ones that output more vertices than they get as input) are pretty slow across the board. Non-expanding geometry shaders (such as the one you'd use for this) are usually at least acceptable in performance, and I think on newer hardware they are pretty good overall.

Note that unless your lighting computation is absurdly complicated or you are using extremely underpowered hardware, moving the lighting computation up in the pipeline probably won't save you too much: cost is like to be dominated by the actual launch of pixel shader threads.

Answer (score 1):

Another simple approach is to compute the (screenspace) face normal in the fragment shader using the derivative of the screenspace position. It is very simple to implement and even performs well.

I have written an example of it [here](http://www.kickjs.org/example/shader_editor/shader_editor.html#ahFzfmtpY2tzdGFydGVuZ2luZXJiCxIWb3JnLmtpY2tqcy5zaGFyZWQuVXNlciIbbW9ydGVuQG5vYmVsLWpvZXJnZW5zZW4uY29tDAsSGG9yZy5raWNranMuc2hhcmVkLlNoYWRlciINTm9ybWFsIHNoYWRlcgw) (requires a WebGL capable browser):

Vertex:

```
attribute vec3 vertex;

uniform mat4 _mvProj;
uniform mat4 _mv;

varying vec3 fragVertexEc;

void main(void) {
    gl_Position = _mvProj * vec4(vertex, 1.0);
    fragVertexEc = (_mv * vec4(vertex, 1.0)).xyz;
}
```

Fragment:

```
#ifdef GL_ES
precision highp float;
#endif

#extension GL_OES_standard_derivatives : enable

varying vec3 fragVertexEc;

const vec3 lightPosEc = vec3(0,0,10);
const vec3 lightColor = vec3(1.0,1.0,1.0);

void main()
{
    vec3 X = dFdx(fragVertexEc);
    vec3 Y = dFdy(fragVertexEc);
    vec3 normal=normalize(cross(X,Y));

    vec3 lightDirection = normalize(lightPosEc - fragVertexEc);

    float light = max(0.0, dot(lightDirection, normal));

    gl_FragColor = vec4(normal, 1.0);
    gl_FragColor = vec4(lightColor * light, 1.0);
}
```

Comment: Note that in this case the position is calculated per-fragment, not once at the centroid. That means for non-directional lights or shadow-casting lights the lighting won't be the same across the triangle.

Comment: Thanks for the example! But what is the meaning `dFdx` and `dFdy` functions? How should I interpret their output values? According to my initial research, they run "between" four (right?) fragment shader threads and operate on vectors belonging to two different coordinate systems (3D _view space_ and 2D _viewport space_, right?). But what do they mean? How to "visualize" the concept behind them?

Comment: In this usage you can think of dFdx and dFdy as the slope or the tangent of the current triangle. In more abstract terms dFdx and dYdy tells you what happens to a given variable when you move one pixel horizontally or vertically. Or in more mathematical terms the derivative of a variable in respect the x or y direction.

Comment: As I understand it: `dFdx` returns the difference quotient of the vertex attribute interpolation function, taken along the X axis of the 2D _viewport space_, but regarding vectors existing in 3D _eye space_ (e.g., position vector). Or simply: tells in what direction does the attribute change between "me" and "my" next horizontal neighbour (on the screen). Right?

Comment: @KrzysztofAbramowicz: There is no such thing as viewport space. The viewport is used to restrict where images are projected to on the image plane, but the coordinate space is actually window space.